# Please tell me why this condition is always true

Tags: c, enums

```
enum bool{true,false};
void main()
{
    if(true==(2==3))
    {
        printf("true\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("false\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how do you not recognize this womp?
of course, you've got syntax errors up the wazoo

Comment: There, fixed those syntax error for ya' (I think).

Comment: If you find someones answer useful, mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm upvoting this Q - the original was slightly hard to comprehend but I'd rather people fix it than vote it down.

Comment: +1 cause this totally didn't deserve a -1.

Comment: This makes me want to cry. If it were interesting, it would be a trick question. According to the other answers, you're basically playing games with the compiler - games which would annoy me, were i to take the time to understand what you've written. No more dumb questions, please - let's have something simple yet interesting?

Comment: This is a C++ torture/trick question - which makes no sense for real world applications - You would... should never do things like this. Basically redefining true to be 0 (default first value for an enum)

Comment: @Justice, the problem is: who define "dumb"? There are many questions here that I would consider too easy (but I've been in the industry for nearly 30 years). Yet, if I were to ask an F# question, it would probably be at a similar level to this one. It may well be that Srie is a database guru alongside Date and Codd but is just having troubles with C (he wouldn't be the first). I'm pretty certain the powers that be have stated that easy questions are fine, as long as they're about programming and have a definite answer. This seems okay on both those counts.

Answer (score 12):

The enum true is 0 in this case.

so:

> 0==(2==3)
>   0==(0)
>   1

1 is true.  Thus this conditional is always true.

Answer (score 6):

In your enumeration, `true` has the constant value 0, and `false` has the constant value 1.

In C, the result of an equality comparison (2==3) is either 0 for not equal, or 1 for equal. Your code is:

```
if ( 0 == (2==3) )
```

or

```
if ( 0 == 0 )
```

Which is clearly true.

Answer (score 5):

It's because the default starting point for `enum`s in `C` is 0, which happens to be false, not true.

You should use `enum bool {false, true}` instead. And please don't use abominations like

```
if (x == true)
if (x == false)
```

at all. You'd be better off with

```
if (x)
if (!x)
```

By all means, use `true` and `false` for setting booleans but you should never have to test them that way. Especially since the definition is zero/non-zero, not zero/one.

I've always liked (if you really have to):

```
#define false (1==0)
#define true  (1==1)
```

That's at least guaranteed to work.

Comment: This and Chris Arguin 's answer are the only ones that are both correct and complete.

Comment: What do you mean, "guaranteed to work"? Comparing any non-zero value to 'true' using the == operator does not evaluate as true. E.g. 2==(1==1) evaluates as false. So in that sense, 'true' is 1 and only 1. Basically it's not valid to use == operator for boolean comparison.

Comment: No, I'm still dead set against comparing with true/false, you should use 'if(x)', not 'if(x==true)'. I mean (1==1) will give you the 'real' value of true (as the compiler sees it) rather than what you think it may be.

Comment: It makes no difference if you understand the standard and how booleans work - this is just a trick for those yet to suffer the pain of 30 years of C coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because true is false and false is true.

Comment: "this statement is false" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Defining the enums 'true' and 'false' is a bad idea anyway. In C, 'false' is zero, and 'true' is non-zero... true is not necessarily '1'.